# NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting this error:`NumberFormatException: null`  when I am trying to add score/points to my app.

I created separated table for this because I need multiple tables .
I have no clue what the problem is so thanks to you all.

```
  if(count==4) {

          my_db=new DBHelper(this);
          sqdb = my_db.getWritableDatabase();

          Cursor c_oldPoints= sqdb.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,null,DBHelper.NICKNAME+"=?",new String[]{Username},null,null,null);
          int col_Points=c_oldPoints.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.POINTS);
          c_oldPoints.moveToFirst();

          while (!c_oldPoints.isAfterLast())
             {
              OldPoints=c_oldPoints.getString(col_Points);
                            c_oldPoints.moveToNext();
             }
         sqdb.close();

         int OldP = Integer.parseInt(OldPoints);
         OldP+=countPoints;
         String SoldP = Integer.toString(OldP);
         my_db=new DBHelper(this);
         sqdb = my_db.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
         cv.put(my_db.POINTS,SoldP);
         Cursor c = sqdb.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,null,DBHelper.NICKNAME+"=?",new String[]{Username},null,null,null);

         c.moveToFirst();
         while (!c.isAfterLast())
         {
            sqdb.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,cv, DBHelper.POINTS+"=?",new String[]{OldPoints});
            c.moveToNext();
         }
         sqdb.close();
         countPoints=0;

  }
```

This is the logcat :-

```
2019-05-15 18:18:14.101 8513-8513/com.example.user.soundsequ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.soundsequ, PID: 8513
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
        at com.example.user.soundsequ.Game.onClick(Game.java:353)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: `OldPoints` might be `null`, so check what your database request returns.

Comment: Skizo-ozᴉʞS I did what you asked

Comment: Tom how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be in this line

```
int OldP = Integer.parseInt(OldPoints);
```

The error is saying that the value of OldPoints is not a string that can be converted to an integer e.g. if it were A or null;

As such either a value extracted from the POINTS column is not a numeric or the value of Username does not match the column NICKNAME in a row. In which case OldPoints will be whatever value it has been set to before the loop.

As the data itself is not available you need to ascertain which of the two situations is causing the issue.

I'd suggest adding some Logging in to determine which.

e.g. by using something like :-

```
      OldPoints = "my debugging value";
      Log.d("MYDEBUGGING","OldPoints, before doing anything is " + OldPoints);
      Cursor c_oldPoints= sqdb.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,null,DBHelper.NICKNAME+"=?",new String[]{Username},null,null,null);
      int col_Points=c_oldPoints.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.POINTS);
      c_oldPoints.moveToFirst();

      while (!c_oldPoints.isAfterLast())
         {
          
          OldPoints=c_oldPoints.getString(col_Points);
                        c_oldPoints.moveToNext();
          Log.d("MYDEBUGGING","Extracted the value " + OldPoints + " from position + String.valueOf(c_oldPoints.getPosition());
         }
     sqdb.close();

     Log.d("MYDEBUGGING","Trying to convert the value " + OldPoints + " to an integer");
     int OldP = Integer.parseInt(OldPoints);
```

You could also not make the above changes and add a breakpoint (on the line initially indicated) and then use Run/Debug App and inspect the variables (or use multiple breakpoints at suitable places). You may find this useful in regard to debugging [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug).

The following code protects against the exception and also protects against an attempt being made to update a non-existent user :-

```
    if (count == 4) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqdb = my_db.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c_oldPoints= sqdb.query(
                DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,null,
                DBHelper.NICKNAME+"=?",
                new String[]{Username},
                null,null,null
        );
        int col_Points=c_oldPoints.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.POINTS);
        if (c_oldPoints.moveToFirst()) {
            Oldpoints = c_oldPoints.getString(col_Points);
            //Oldpoints = "oops";
            int OldP = 0;
            boolean can_convert_to_int = true;
            try {
                OldP = Integer.parseInt(Oldpoints) + countPoints;
                can_convert_to_int = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //TODO not necessary probably remove. just for checking the log 
            }

            if (can_convert_to_int) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(DBHelper.POINTS,OldP);
                sqdb.update(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME2,cv, DBHelper.NICKNAME + "=?", new String[]{Username});
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("NICKNAMENOTFOUND","No row was found when attemtping to get the old score for User " + Username);
        }
    }
```

---

## However

I would suggest that you add a couple of methods to your DBHelper class, these being :-

```
public int increasePoints(String user, int points_to_add) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteStatement sql = db.compileStatement(
            "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME2 +
                    " SET " + POINTS + "=" + POINTS + " +?  " +
                    "WHERE "+ NICKNAME + "=?"
    );
    sql.bindLong(1,points_to_add);
    sql.bindString(2,user);
    return sql.executeUpdateDelete();
}

public int getPoints(String user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int rv = -1;
    String whereclause = NICKNAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{user};
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME2,new String[]{POINTS},whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(POINTS));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

The first method **increasePoints** performs the change to the points via an UPDATE sql statement and does away for the need to convert the points extracted as a string to an integer. It returns the number of rows that have been updated (1 if the NICKNAME column is always a unique value, 0 if nothing was updated).

The second method **getPoints** does as it says, it gets the points for the given user, if the user doesn't exist it will return -1.

Your code could then be :-

```
    if (count == 4) {
        boolean updated = false; //TODO remove when happy
        int old_points = my_db.getPoints(Username); //TODO remove when happy
        if (my_db.increasePoints(Username,countPoints) > 0) {
            updated = true;
        }
        int new_points = my_db.getPoints(Username); //TODO remove when happy

        //TODO remove following code when happy
        String result = "The result of the attempt to update the points for user " + Username;
        if (updated) {
            result = result + " was successful. ";
        } else {
            result = result + " was unsuccessful.";
        }
        Log.d("POINTSINCREASE",result +
                " Points were " + String.valueOf(old_points) + " points are now " + String.valueOf(new_points));
    }
```

**Note** where `//TODO remove when happy` is coded the lines are just for testing, so the above could be :-

```
    if (count == 4) {
        my_db.increasePoints(Username,countPoints);
    }
```